# Custom class loader returns NoSuchMethodException in listFilesAndDirs() method call

Tags: java, class, exception, object, classloader

I am trying to invoke the method listFilesAndDirs() of org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils using my own custom class loader. But it returns NoSuchMethodException.

**Code used for method invoke.**

```
MyLoader c=new MyLoader();
Class cls=c.loadClass("org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils");
//to display the available methods
Method m[] = cls.getDeclaredMethods();
for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
  System.out.println(m[i].toString());

// to get a listFilesAndDirs method
Method me=cls.getMethod("listFilesAndDirs",new Class[] { File.class, IOFileFilter.class,
            IOFileFilter.class });
```

**Code used for class loader**

```
public class MyLoader extends ClassLoader {
private  String classPath;
public MyLoader()
{

}
private String jarFile = "D:/Project/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar";;          //Path to the jar file  
private Hashtable classes = new Hashtable(); //used to cache already defined classes  

public Class loadClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {  

return findClass(className);  
}  

public Class findClass(String className) {  
//System.out.println(className+" is loaded by Custom class Loader");


byte classByte[];  
Class result = null;  

result = (Class) classes.get(className); //checks in cached classes  
if (result != null) {  
    return result;  
}  



try {
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(jarFile);  
    classPath=className.replaceAll("\\.", "/");
    JarEntry entry = jar.getJarEntry(classPath + ".class"); 
    if(entry==null)
    {
         return findSystemClass(className);  
    }
    else
    {

    InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(entry);  
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    int nextValue = is.read();  
    while (-1 != nextValue) {  
        byteStream.write(nextValue);  
        nextValue = is.read();  
    }  

    classByte = byteStream.toByteArray(); 
    result = defineClass(className, classByte, 0, classByte.length, null);  
    classes.put(className, result);  
    return result;  
    }
} catch (Exception e) {  
    return null;  
}  


 } 
 }
```

*call of cls.getDeclaredMethods() will return the method* 
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(java.io.File,org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter)

*but cls.getMethod("listFilesAndDirs",new Class[] { File.class, IOFileFilter.class,
            IOFileFilter.class });*
returns the following error

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(java.io.File, org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter, org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1937)
    at Sample.main(Sample.java:30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `getDeclaredMethods()` displays that the class in question has the required method `listFilesAndDirs(java.io.File,org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter)`,

BUT

the parameter types are different from what you pass into `cls.getMethod("listFilesAndDirs",new Class[]{...})` even if it seems that they reference the proper classes.

Your compiled code uses `org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter` class from the context class loader while `cls` expects the same classes from the custom class loader.

One way to make it work is to load `IOFileFilter` from the custom class loader too and then use that class as the second and third item when calling `getMethod`.

```
Class ioFileFilterClass = c.loadClass( "org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter" );
Method me = cls.getMethod( "listFilesAndDirs", new Class[] { File.class, ioFileFilterClass, ioFileFilterClass} );
```

It will solve this particular problem but you will have to write similar code each time you are trying to access classes and methods loaded by the custom class loader.